# Hide one DIV and show another on successful submission of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm using the following snippet of code to post data and submit a form. I have a div with id=form and one with id=thankyou. I'm using $('#thankyou').hide(); to hide the thank you div. On successful submission of the form I need to hide the form div and show the thank you div. All is working as it should i.e. form is submitted and data is stored in a DB but for some reason the hiding and showing of the two div's is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
  $('#thankyou').hide();
  $('.submit-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://ecaddy.co.za/timer/shared/html/entry_form.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data, status) {
        // This is how I'm trying to hide / show the div's.
        $('#form').hide();
        $('#thankyou').show();
        console.log(data)
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is the `$('#form')` being hidden? Or is nothing hiding at all?

Comment: Your code seems correct at first glance. The ajax success console.log() is fired ok? You see it normally in your console?

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: Put a breakpoint in success function. Look if the code has any effect.
Try run the same code from console also

Comment: Can you please show you html code here

Comment: thanks for the quick responses. the first line of code - $('#thankyou').hide(); hides the thankyou div as intended. on submission of the form the form div should hide and the thankyou div shown. Neither of these are working. there don't seem to be any errors in the console.

Comment: You need to post your html as well

Comment: Is the `#thankyou` div inside the form, by any chance?

Comment: In html if your form is nested then it wont work

Comment: okay, seems I was getting an error message in the console - Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ecaddy.co.za/timer/shared/html/entry_form.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). Changed the URL to /timer/shared/html/entry_form.php and all working.